# Add third total row using fnFooterCallback in jQuery DataTables

Tags: datatables

Using the following syntax, I was hoping to add a third and fourth row to my DataTables footer.

```js
var secondRow = $(nRow).next()[0]; 
var nCells = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td');

*var thirdRow = $(nRow).next()[1]; 
var nCells = thirdRow.getElementsByTagName('td');
var fourthRow = $(nRow).next()[2]; 
var nCells = forthRow.getElementsByTagName('td');*
```

While the second row works, the third triggers an error. "thirdRow" is undefined.

Is there a way to add multiple rows within the footer callback?

Answer (score 0):

`$(row).next()` returns a single JQuery object not an array of them, and as with all JQuery objects you can access the underlying JavaScript object by getting the first element of it, and you then execute a JavaScript (not JQuery) function to get the cells.

You could I suppose use your selected element to find the next one

```js
const secondRow = $(nRow).next()[0]; 
const nCells = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td');

const thirdRow = $(secondRow).next()[0];
const nCells = thirdRow.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

but your question is a little bit confusing because you talk about adding new elements to your page but your code is for selecting existing elements from the page.

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Thank you.    I was little confused as well.   I was attempting to build upon another post that added only one addition row.    Thank you so much for your help!